# Problema con scanf, copia por valor

Tags: c, variables, punteros, scanf

El problema que tengo es:

- Llamo a la función scanf en el método copiaValor(int num).
- Tecleo un número entero
- y no se asigna ese valor a la variable local que luego retorno en el main.

(Supongo que no le dará tiempo a leerlo)

No osbtante, si quito el comentario de la llamada al método coparReferencia(int *num)

- no me deja teclear.
- e Imprime el número que escribí anteriormente en el método copiaVarlor().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int num = 50;
    
    //Obtengo dirección de memoria de variable num
    printf("Direccion de num en memoria: %p\n", &num);
    printf("Valor de variable num inicial: %i\n", num);
    
    
    num = copiaValor(num); //llamo a función copiaValor
    printf("Direccion memo: %p\n", &num);
    
    printf("Valor de variable num despues copiaValor: %i\n", num);
    //copiaReferencia(&num);
    
    //printf("numero despues de referencia: %d\n", num);
    
}

int copiaValor(int num){ 
    printf("valor de dirección memoria de num local: %p\n", &num);
    
    //Solicita valor para introducir
    printf("Ingrese el número copia\n");
    scanf("&d", &num);

    printf("valor de num copia: %i\n", num);
    printf("Valor de direccion memo de num local: %p\n", &num);
    
    return num;

}

void copiaReferencia(int *num){
    //Solicita valor para introducir
    printf("Ingrese numero referencia\n");
    scanf(" %d", num);
    
    printf("valor de num refe: %p\n", &num);
    printf("VAlor de num refe dentro del método: %i\n", *num);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no entiendo por qué sucede esto.
Sin embargo, cuando elimino "scanf" y hago un bucle donde incremento el valor en 1 aparece guardado el valor en la variable local y es retornado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si quieres imprimir la dirección de memoria de la variable original, es: `printf("valor de num refe: %p\n", num);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre viene bien leer e intrepretar los mensajes de advertencias que te arroja el compilador:

```
prog.c: In function 'copiaValor':
prog.c:30:11: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
   30 |     scanf("&d", &num);
      |           ^~~~
```

Efectivamente, el método `copiarValor` está mal, ya que la llamada a `scanf` no está bien configurada. Ese `"&d"` debería ser `"%d"`

```
printf("Ingrese el número copia\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Por otro lado, este método no debería recibir ningún entero, ya el valor de la variable pasada como argumento no se utiliza en ningún momento. Para esto existen las variables locales:

```
int copiaValor(void)
{
    int num;

    // ...

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por ayudarme. Ahora me funciona bien. No me di cuenta de ese detalle del scanf :)